# PHPSESSID empty after server restart

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am currently developing locally using vagrant and [scotchbox](https://box.scotch.io/)

Recently I have noticed that after closing the server using `vagrant suspend` and then upon accessing a page after starting the server I receive this error

`Warning: session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /var/www/public/server/_core.php on line 2`

Line 2 being,

`session_start();`

I then open dev tools to inspect the cookie which results in the cookie being empty.

Now I understand that there is a low possibility this might occur in a live environment, I'd like to understand and account for it happening.

Through some research I have discovered that this could happen due to a hacker changing the cookie in an attempt to expose file structure and account names for further hacking, but as previously mentioned in my case the cookie is empty.

I am guessing the cookie is empty because the server might destroy sessions when it suspends but I am unsure on why it would replace the string with nothing rather than regenerate a new session?

Any information on this would be great, feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: since sessions are transient, I wouldn't see this as a problem... It would happen only if user was browsing your website, and the server restarted at the same time. Highly unlikely (especially when production servers almost never restart). It's weird though, for sure.

Comment: In your opinion would it worth adding an if to check if it is empty and then remove the cookie if it is?

Comment: idk it's such a corner case that I wouldn't invest my time in it, but it surely won't hurt anything if you add it